# Show specific files to delete in Manage Storage app menu

Tags: ios

On the iPhone, when I go to Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Storage / Manage Storage > Music, I can see how much space is taken up by specific audiobooks, artists, etc, and delete any of those files or collections of files. Is presenting users with a per-file breakdown of how much space they are using within the context of my apps something I can do as well? If so, how?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image: Examining the Music app storage]